# Change single column vector into multiple columns using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have values in a single column and multiple rows in this form (as a Pandas dataframe)

```
import pandas as pd

#Create data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.linspace(1,20,20))

print(df)

1
2
:
19
20
```

How can I take these values and split them into multiple rows do that each column has some multiple of the original matrix say 5, e.g.

```
1 6 11 16
2 7 12 17
3 8 13 18
4 9 14 19
5 10 15 20
```

Comment: Will you always have access to the data before making it into a dataframe? Cause if so you can just reshape the original array: `pd.DataFrame(np.linspace(1,20,20).reshape(-1, 5).T)`

Comment: No I won't, I can import it as a numpy array though. The data is coming from a text file generated using c++. @user15270287

Comment: If you can import it as a numpy array, then just reshaping it before converting it to a dataframe should do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say I want to take a 1D array or a Series of length 20 and I want to split it into 4 equal sized columns of size 5. This is how I would do it:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.linspace(1,20,20).reshape(-1, 5).T)
```